# Show that $x^2+xy+2y^2$ is equivalent to $x^2-xy+2y^2$ and that $3x^2+xy+4y^2$ is not equivalent to $3x^2-xy+4y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

i am trying to prove that  $x^2+xy+2y^2$ is equivalent to $x^2-xy+2y^2$ and that $3x^2+xy+4y^2$ is not equivalent to $3x^2-xy+4y^2$.

As for the first problem, i am trying to find a matrix $M$ with integer coefficients and determinant 1 that takes me from the first quadratic forms to the second one , but i am not able to find it. As for the second problem, i dont know where to start. Can i get some hints please ?

Comment: I found $M = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & 1\cr} $ that takes me from $x^2-xy+2y^2$ to $x^2+xy+2y^2$ , but i still need hints for the second problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a small finite set of matrices that take us from  $3 x^2 + xy + 4 y^2$ to $3 x^2 - xy + 4 y^2.$  Call one
$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & q \\
r & s
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Necessary conditions are that the left column give form value $3,$ and the right column give form value $4.$ That is
$$ 3 p^2 + pr + 4 r^2 = 3, $$
$$ 3 q^2 + q s + 4 s^2 = 4. $$
One pair of examples  is
$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}
\right),
$$
$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Both of these have determinant $-1,$ the traditional word for such a pair of forms is "opposite."
The remaining task for you is to find out any other matrices $P,$ or calculate that there are no others, to conclude that the determinant is always $-1.$ This will not be hard: I think there are very few ways to get 
$$ 3 p^2 + pr + 4 r^2 = 3, $$ and very few ways to get
$$ 3 q^2 + q s + 4 s^2 = 4. $$

Indeed, multiplying by numbers and completing the square two times, we get separate
$$  3 x^2 + x y + 4 y^2 \geq \frac{47}{16} x^2 \approx 2.9375 x^2, $$
$$  3 x^2 + x y + 4 y^2 \geq \frac{47}{12} y^2 \approx 3.9167 y^2. $$
We can only get $3$ when $y=0.$ We can only get $4$ when $|y| \leq 1$ and $|x| \leq 1,$ very few possibilities to check.